# Client Side ADFS configuration for SAML based WebSSO protocol

Tags: asp.net, wcf, single-sign-on, adfs

I just started looking in ADFS and it looks very confusing.
I need to setup AD FS for my client using SAML based WebSSO protocol.

I figured out configuring Ad FS server side , but dont know how to configure the client side for this.

What would i need to mention in my web.config to achieve this.
(Like where do I mention certificate details and other required wcf related settings)
Do i need to write any special code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SAML, you need a [client side SAML stack](https://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).

Also, the SAML protocol is not a good fit for WCF. The WIF active profile would be a much better fit.